# How do I scale three independent variables in a Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate

#### cross-posted on the [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/107224?p_p_auth=X7DhCNuZ) forum

I'm trying to ilustrate the difficulties in assigning bins to a data set and then running a comparison of the bins against a binomial distribution for all values- n, p. The code I have so far is (mostly thanks to Nasser):

```
Manipulate[Show[Histogram[dataB, {-0.5, 7.5, c}, "PDF"], 
  DiscretePlot[PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, p], x], {x, 0, 20}, 
    PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]], ImagePadding -> All],
  {{c, 8, "Column Width"}, 0, 4, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{n, 7, "Number Of Quarters"}, 1, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{p, 0.5, "Fair Coin Toss"}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

The remaining problem, scaling the number of quarters in the binomial to the width of the X-axis. Right now my X-axis ranges from 0 to 7.5 in agreement with the range of the numbers in my data set. I think I need two X-axes. One to illustrate the range of the numbers in my data set, and a second X-axis to illustrate the number of quarters in the binomial ensemble (1 to 20). Here is a data set (Binomial[n=7,p=0.65]):
dataB = {0.38, 1.39, 1.51, 1.75, 1.97, 2.19, 2.43, 2.49, 2.51, 2.52, 
  2.71, 2.77, 2.81, 2.92, 2.94, 2.95, 3.00, 3.01, 3.29, 3.36, 3.42, 
  3.43, 3.45, 3.47, 3.49, 3.51, 3.52, 3.53, 3.54, 3.55, 3.56, 3.57, 
  3.58, 3.59, 3.60, 3.70, 3.75, 3.80, 4.00, 4.10, 4.12, 4.15, 4.18, 
  4.19, 4.20, 4.21, 4.22, 4.23, 4.24, 4.27, 4.30, 4.35, 4.37, 4.40, 
  4.41, 4.42, 4.43, 4.44, 4.45, 4.46, 4.50, 4.51, 4.52, 4.53, 4.54, 
  4.55, 4.60, 4.61, 4.62, 4.63, 4.70, 4.72, 4.75, 4.79, 4.82, 4.85, 
  4.86, 4.87, 4.89, 4.92, 5.10, 5.15, 5.16, 5.17, 5.18, 5.19, 5.20, 
  5.25, 5.27, 5.28, 5.30, 5.31, 5.32, 5.35, 5.37, 5.40, 5.42, 5.45, 
  5.50, 5.55, 5.57, 5.62, 5.64, 5.65, 5.70, 5.77, 5.82, 5.87, 5.89, 
  5.94, 5.99, 6.00, 6.01, 6.22, 6.23, 6.42, 6.43, 6.44, 6.46, 6.47, 
  6.48, 6.49, 6.50, 6.51, 6.57, 6.59, 6.64, 6.75, 7.00}

Comment: Could you provide a small data set, `dataB`, so that the code can be executed?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `DiscretePlot` I believe the best option (for visual comparisons) is to use a `Plot`.

So, my suggestion is to use:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Histogram[dataB, {0, 20, c}, "PDF"], 
  Plot[Evaluate@PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, p], x], {x, 0, 20} , 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, PlotRange -> All, 
   Exclusions -> None]], {{c, .5, "Column Width"}, .05, 4, .05, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{n, 7, "Number Of Quarters"}, 1, 20, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{p, 0.65, "Fair Coin Toss"}, 0, 1, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Dear Rod Lm- Thanks for the help. Your solution works, but I'm not wanting to display a binomial distribution as a smooth histogram. Looks like I have to offer up side by side manipulates to get my point across. Thanks again. @Rod Lm